Indefinite Integral of $\sec^{4/3} x$
I am a $12^{\text{th}}$ grader who has recently started learning integration. I came across $$\int {(x^2+1)}^{-1/3} \mathrm dx $$ by accident due to a misprint in my assignment sheet, so I thought about it.  I substituted $$\ x = \tan t
    $$ and obtained $$\int\sec^{4/3} t \mathrm dt$$  I tried fumbling around with trigonometric identities, but nothing seemed to help. Can anyone out there please help me with this? Does it have an elementary-antiderivative, and how do I find this? Thanks in advance.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2CCbrt%5B1%2BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%5D%2Cx%5D

WolframAlpha gives an answer in terms of the hypergeometric function, so it is likely there is no elementary antiderivative at all.

What is the hypergeometric function in simple terms?

@RakshithPL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function

It should be possible to find an antiderivative in terms of elliptic integrals. Still non-elementary, but much less esoteric than a hypergeometric result.

It was an assignment sheet given by my teacher.

@DavidH, how would one go about doing it in terms of elliptic integrals?

@RakshithPL You'd start by using a substitution like $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^{2}+1}}=y$. After the substitution, the radical term in the integrand is then a square-root of a quartic polynomial. From that point, there are well-known algorithms for reducing it to the "standard" elliptic integrals.

IDK about elliptic integrals, but the $x$-integrand is expressible in terms of the hypergeometric ${}_2F_1$. You may be able to find the antiderivative among one of the identities listed here.

$$\int(1+x^n)^{\frac{-1}{m}},dx=x^2,_2F^1\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{m}; 1+\frac{1}{n};-x^n\right)$$

As the comment says, using hypergeometric integrals, we find:
$$
\int (1+x^n)^{\frac{-1}{m}}\mathrm dx=x^2\,_2F^1\left(\frac1n,\frac1m;1+\frac1n;-x^{n}\right)
$$
Since $n=2$ and $m=3$, therefore, the hypergeometric series is:
$$_2F^1\left(\frac12,\frac13;\frac32;-x^{2}\right)$$
According to definition, this hypergeometric series can be written as:
$$_2F^1(a,b;c;-x^{2})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(c)_n}\frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!}$$
Putting $a=\frac12$, $b=\frac13$ and $c=\frac32$, we get:
$$
_2F^1\left(\frac12,\frac13;\frac32;-x^{2}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac12)_n(\frac13)_n}{(\frac32)_n}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n!}
$$
The series at the left can be expanded as:
$$
\frac19x^2-\frac25x^4+\frac5{18}x^6...
$$
Therefore, it finally results into:
$$
\int(1+x^2)^{-\frac13}\mathrm dx=x^2\left(\frac19x^2-\frac25x^4+\frac5{18}x^6...\right)
$$
$$
=x^4\left(\frac19-\frac25x^2+\frac5{18}x^4...\right)
$$
Edit: The series converges for any values of $x$ since the function itself is defined for those values of $x$. There was a major mistake in my previous result. Thanks for pointing it out.
